# Maven-based project withn JBehave and Selenium failing to initialize CDI

Tags: maven-3, cdi, jbehave

I need to write UATs based on JBehave for a Maven-based web application.
The tests are executed, but the @Injected class is not initialized, bevor the test starts.

I use the jbehave-maven-plugin like this:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>unpack-view-resources</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>unpack-view-resources</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>embeddable-stories</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Stories.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <ignoreFailureInStories>true</ignoreFailureInStories>
                    <ignoreFailureInView>true</ignoreFailureInView>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run-stories-as-embeddables</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

As I use CDI in the tests, I need to initialize weld, so it works with the tests. But initialization of CDI doesn't occur and I get NPEs with the testing code.

I declared dependencies like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbehave-weld</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
      <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbehave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
  <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

What has to be done, to initialize CDI before the tests get started?

Comment: Is there `META-INF/beans.xml` file in your project ? If no, then you must create it, here is an example of [empty beans.xml](https://gist.github.com/sejersbol/845053) just copy it and paste to resources in your project . How do you bootstrap and initialize Weld in Java code, could you show this part of code ?

Comment: He must not. It is optional in version 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using an "outdated" version of CDI. There is a brand new version of the specification, CDI 2.0. Feel free to use that. There is  an implementation already done - [Weld version 3.0](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/download/). As an alternative, you can use Apache OpenWebBeans, which is yet another implementation of CDI already supporting CDI 2.0.

Anyway, back to your question. You do not mention what kind of tests are you going to implement. If you'd like to use dependency injection for tests, simply write a JUnit runner providing all the dependencies. There is a [nice tutorial](http://memorynotfound.com/java-se-unit-testing-cdi-junit-jboss-weld-se/) to do just that. In that tutorial, you can see this snippet of code:

```
package com.memorynotfound.cdi.test;

import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

public class WeldJUnit4Runner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public WeldJUnit4Runner(Class<Object> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object createTest() {
        final Class<?> test = getTestClass().getJavaClass();
        return WeldContext.INSTANCE.getBean(test);
    }
}
```

Annotate your tests with @RunWith(WeldJUnit4Runner.class) and you have dependency injection capabilities in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm doing UATs (user acceptance tests) based on the running application and selenium based tests.
I have an alternative versions of the tests for a similar project based on outdated Cucumber tests, which I have to rewrite/refactor/redo using JBehave. So, all the issues of accessing UI components from tests et al is solved. I just need a way to work using CDI with JBehave.